# Differences in turtle-per-patch fillup in even and odd scenarios?

Tags: patch, netlogo

I'm new at netlogo, and in my model, I'm trying to make it so there's one turtle per patch, so that all the patches are filled up with one turtle instead of them overlapping each other. The code for that part of the model is

```
  to solid
  set color blue
  set xcor random sqrt number-of-particles - number-of-particles / 2
  set ycor random sqrt number-of-particles - number-of-particles / 2
  ifelse any? patches with [pcolor = black and count turtles-here = 0]
  [move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = black and count turtles-here = 0]]
  [die]
  end
```

I've been trying it out with different variables, but it works for odd "Volume" (amount of patches in each row) but not the even ones.

(even numbered one) [Link 1](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t34.0-12/10475841_911170682242453_224779359_n.jpg?oh=c6e1e457b9918b4ccdb02d8494fab5c7&oe=539EAFA8&__gda__=1402900663_094e88b6a293a451f904b07f0540eda2)

(odd numbered one) [Link 2](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/10455405_911170645575790_1667715601_n.jpg?oh=6355d192f227f2ef335a5d09bbd1fa5d&oe=539ED981&__gda__=1402916753_1d1c557c9566d4212d882250093ff802)

how would i make it so that it works for both odd and even numbers? thanks!

This is my full setup code. Sorry that I posted them in my comments, this is my first time on stackoverflow.

```
to Setup-Container   
  ca
  cro 4
  [set color black
    rt 45
    fd Volume * sqrt 2 / 2 
    rt 135
    pd
    set pen-size 6
    fd Volume
    die
  ]
  ask patches
  [ifelse pxcor <= Volume / 2 and pxcor >= Volume / 2 * -1
    and pycor <= Volume / 2 and pycor >= Volume / 2 * -1
    [set pcolor black] [set pcolor black + 3]
  ] 
end

; Creates a number of particles, which depends on the corresponding slider. 
; Executes certain commands depending on the temperature slider. 
to Setup-Particles
  ask turtles
  [die]
cro number-of-particles  
  ask turtles [
    set shape "water"
    if Temperature <= 0 ; freezing point is 0 degrees celsius.
    [ice-cube]  
    if Temperature > 0 and Temperature < 100 
    [water]
    if Temperature >= 100 ; boiling point is 100 degrees celsius.
    [water-vapor]
  ]
end
```

Comment: I can't see anything that has to do with "even" vs "odd" volume. As best as I can tell, the reason you have holes in your "even" version is just that you don't have enough turtles to fill out the space... Why do you think there is anything else going on?

Comment: well a container with volume 24 has holes while a container with volume 25 does not. That doesn't really make sense to me, because why would a container with a volume of just one more than another one fail to fill up all the turtles, while the container with volume 24 is perfectly fine? (screenshots are reference)

Comment: Does this happen consistently (i.e. everytime you run your model)? What about other volumes? (20, 21, 22, 23, etc.)

Comment: Also, it seems like something else in your model is creating particles: in both of your screenshots, the `Number-of-Particles` is set to 100, which is clearly not enough to fill either sizes of containers.

Comment: In cases where you see holes, you should verify things in the [command center](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/interface.html#commandcenter): `show count patches with [pcolor=black]` and `show count turtles`; then you'll know for sure if you have enough turtles to fill out your patches...

Comment: I see what you mean. I tried it out and I realized that you were right, so I added code to fix that error. Thank you so much for all the help!! (Definitely putting you in our info tab for credit in the project!)

Answer (score 2):

There's actually a primitive that just creates a turtle on a given patch: [`sprout`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#sprout). So, `ask patches [ sprout 1 ]` would create one turtle on each patch.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I did not want to to use sprout, as I've tried implementing it in my code again and again, and it did not produce the result I wanted. Whenever I try to do that, I'd just get a bunch of rainbow-colored turtles freezing netlogo.

Comment: Could you post the code you're using to create the turtles?

Answer (score 1):

Bryan's answer is most probably the right one, here: if your main requirement is to have *one turtle per patch*, [`sprout`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#sprout) is the way to go.

A few more comments:

- In the screenshots you've shown us, you control your "volume" and your number of particles separately, so there is aways a chance that your container will be either too big or too small for the number of particles you want. If you really want a one-to-one relationship between the size of your container and the number of particles, you should really have a single parameter for both.
- `sprout` allows you to give commands to the newly created turtles. If you don't want them to be "rainbow colored", you can do: `ask patches with [pcolor = black] [sprout 1 [set color blue]]`.
- In your original code, you set the `xcor` and the `ycor` of your turtles... and then immediately move them. The point will be moot if you use `sprout`, but I wanted to point out that these two lines were unnecessary.

If you still have trouble with `sprout`, I'd suggest you ask a separate question and show us what you tried. We may able to help you...

Comment: That part of the code (xcor and ycor) were to do something else I wanted my turtles to do. If the countainer was too big for the amount of particles, I wanted the turtles to move to any empty close as close to the origin as possible, and if the container were too small, I'd want them to either overlap but still be full, or die.

Comment: What you have expressed in your comment is a different requirement than the one you have expressed in your question... which one are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: The first one. This comment is just a side note that explains the other part of the code that isn't related to my question right now. (although answering that would also be helpful).

Comment: is there really no way to fix the code i had earlier to include even numbers? I'm really trying to avoid sprout.

Comment: The only reason you have given us so far for wanting to avoid `sprout` is that you haven't been able to make it work _yet_. That's not really compelling... :) And regarding the "odd" vs. "even" thing, it's really hard for us to figure it out if we don't know exactly how you set up your container. If that's really what's bothering you, you should post your setup code as well...

Comment: the reason why i'm avoiding sprout is because i know that in order to make it work with my code, I'll have to change a lot more of my code than just that one part, and with my level of knowledge of netlogo, I know that this will be leaving me completely frazzled as I have about 16 hours to complete this project. I know it's not a good excuse, but I'm hoping you could help me out of my misery!

Comment: Posting code in the comments of two separate answers is not optimal... you should edit your question and post the code there...